How to add a GIF to the splash screen?
How can I add a GIF to the splash screen? How can I modify its duration, depending on the launch time of the app?
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        };
        Timer opening = new Timer();
        opening.schedule(task, 5000);
    }
}

The duration is fixed here, how can I make it dynamic?

Rather than having dynamic timing, I would suggest to register callback. Once the background task is completed, you can call callback. In callback, you can start a new activity or home screen.
I would also advise against keeping the splash screen for too long, as it may give users the impression that the app is stuck or not working.
However, if it's a requirement, you can display a progress bar indicating the loading process, similar to how it's done in games, to reassure users that the app is working.
